# BIOS password reset for HP probook 450 G1

Tags: windows-7, boot, motherboard, bios, passwords

I forgot my BIOS administrator password and I have tried the cmospwd-5.0 tool. I have managed to kill my BIOS password. However, now when I reboot this machine and try to gain access to the BIOS settings, I end up getting stuck on the HP - white background - screen that reads:

> The CMOS checksum is invalid. The CMOS will be set to the default
>   configuration and will be rebooted. Please check your BIOS setup
>   options to see if they change.
>
> CMOS reset (502)
>
> ENTER - Reboot the system

The machine then automatically boots to Windows after about 40 seconds. However it still prompts me for a BIOS password when I reboot and try to gain access to the actual BIOS settings. What further could I do to try to resolve this issue?

Comment: @DavidPostill this sounds like something I could try but I'll leave it for fear of having my computer lock up. HP probook products do not have any solutions for a backdoor BIOS password entry save for a customized solution obtained directly from HP support or so it seems. You have to have the current password before you can change to a new password using the BCU downloaded from the HP support site. My worst fear is that I no longer have access to my BIOS settings until I get a solution..and I seem to have run out of options!

Comment: ***Dear Customer,

 

Welcome to HP Support Forum and we are glad to assist you.

 

This is to inform you that all HP Business Notebooks such as Probooks or Elitebooks have more stringent security than consumer models infact they don't produce 'halt codes', the password cannot be derived from the Serial Number and the code is stored in non-volatile memory so removing the RTC cell will not reset the password in this case.

 

Please have a look at this link. 

http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/49497-HP-​​Probook-Elitebook-BIOS-Password-Reset-Utility***